# the meaning of a cinch to fall off

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "Jeez. This is terrible. I made a terrible mistake."
>
> "What is it?"
>
> "The wrong recipe. Jeez."
>
> "But I drank it. You said if I drank I could become a Warrior. You
>   swore to God, Duddy."
>
> "It's terrible," Duddy said, "but this means ***your breezer is a cinch
>   to fall off*** and you'll never grow a bush. And Milty, if a guy doesn't
>   grow a bush..."
>
> Milty ran off crying and that night he was violently ill.
>
> "What is it, pussy-lamb?"
>
> "I'm never going to grow a bush, Mummy."
>
> -The Apprenticeship of Duddy Kravitz by Mordecai Richler -

This is [the link to the dialogue](https://books.google.ru/books?id=XNVuITZr9EMC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=%22Jeez.+This+is+terrible.+I+made+a+terrible+mistake.%22&source=bl&ots=YOUxLJYGCn&sig=vDHkT2nXKVLvVoWGSxMA0lxlW58&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqyp24xcXTAhWCjiwKHULmCnEQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Jeez.%20This%20is%20terrible.%20I%20made%20a%20terrible%20mistake.%22&f=false), and  I am guessing the 'Breezer' is a 'mixed drink' and a 'cinch' is a 'thing with certainty'.

Can I take this as "**a cinch to make the hair fall off**"?

***I am terribly sorry that I had read the "beezer" to be "breezer" and uploaded this non sense. I hope you find at least some comfort that I'd been going through page after page to figure out what the "breezer" means before I uploaded this.***

Comment: Where did you find that definition of "cinch"?

Comment: @Catija: form here http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cinch                          
  b. A sure thing; a certainty: Their team is a cinch to win the tournament.

Comment: Ah. Interesting. As a note, it's usually helpful to include that sort of thing in your question. I've not actually heard it used that way. The only way I've heard it is as a synonym of "easy". See... even native speakers don't know everything :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the word in the original is actually [*beezer*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/beezer), not *breezer*; this is apparently an occasional slang term for *nose*. You are right about *cinch*, and in this context *bush* means pubic hair. So all together the bully is telling poor little Milty that

> Your nose is sure to fall off, and you'll never grow any pubic hair.

Answer (score 1):

A "cinch" is task that is very easy. Like, "This job is a cinch". It's also used to mean that success in some endeavor is likely. Like, "You're a cinch to win the contest." The use here appears to be a variation on that, some event is likely in general.

I don't know a meaning for "breezer" that is relevant here. There is an alcoholic drink called a "breezer" but that doesn't really make sense here. It's not the drink that's going to fall off. I searched several slang dictionaries and while they had many definitions for "breezer", none made sense in context.

"Bush" is a slang term for a woman's pubic hair. Which doesn't quite make sense here as he's talking about a male, but perhaps some use it for men's pubic hair also. That would seem to make sense in context. This would be consistent with the fact that is mother is offended by his remark about it.

Slang changes constantly and is different in different regions, so nailing down unfamiliar slang is difficult.